# Pagination data division

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

What I am trying to accomplish is something like this say Users::paginate(26)

now in my view

it should be displayed like this

> user-1, user 2
>
> newline then i will chunk it to 4
>
> user-3, user-4, user-5, user-6  -- row 1
>
> user-7, user-8,user-9,user-10 -- row 2
>
> etc..

I am done with the chunk part, the only thing i am having a hard time is getting the first two then chunk the 3rd data until the last

i am not sure how to accomplish that since

```
$users->chunk(4)` //only divide it by 4
```

I also tried

```
$users_top = Users::get();
$user_bottom = Users::whereNotIn['id', $top[0]->id, $top[1]->id]->get();
```

but it seems there is a much more simpler logic than that

Edit:
if I use it with splice the pagination would be gone

Comment: Just use my solution, but first, copy `$users` to another variable like `$pages` or whatever, then use that variable in your view to paginate. This should work.

Comment: If  the post below answers your question please may you mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with a full collection

```
$users = Users::get(); // 100 users 
$topUsers = $users->take(2); // you have 2 users in the top variable
$users = $users->splice(0,2);// from index 0, remove 2. 98 left.
```

I think that's it. You have two collections. One with 2 users, another with 98.

Comment: You are  welcome. If this fixed your issue, please mark the answer. Thanks :)